# Excel VBA running a function on every cell in a row with a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to run a function called ToNum on every cell in a row with a value that will convert a cell contents to a string. Here is my code below but I am getting a compile error, can anyone assist and let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub ConvRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Variant

    Set rng = Range("A8:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = ToNum(cell.Value)
    Next

End Sub
Function ToNum(X As Variant) As String
    Dim A As String
    A = Trim(Str(X))
    ToNum = A
End Function
```

Comment: what error is it exactly?

Comment: Why declare a function? Just say `cell.Value = Trim(Str(cell.Value))`

Comment: thanks I removed the .Select and now there is no error but its not converting my numbers to a string in column A.  the function ToNum works but am I not implementing it correctly in my sub ConvRows() ?

Comment: and thanks I tried cell.Value = Trim(Str(cell.Value)) as well but its not converting my numbers to strings

Comment: You need to set the numberformat of the range to text `rng.Numberformat = "@"` before converting the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points to comment. To avoid the type mismatch error on cells that already contain a string, you could put your call to `ToNum` in an `if` statement in your subroutine like this:

```
If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
  cell.Value = ToNum(cell.Value)
End If
```

That should keep the subroutine from touching cells that are already strings.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Function ToNum(X As Variant) As String
    Dim A As String
    A = Trim(Str(X))
    ToNum = "'" & A
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Gary!! that worked BUT only issue is on cells that already hold string values, how do I get these cells to be left alone? because I am getting a type mismatch error if the cell is already a string